# Add doctype to an Iframe using javaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to add Doctype to an iframe once its loaded.
I have tried the following script without any luck:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ms-dlgFrame').ready(function(){
     var iframe = $('.ms-dlgFrame');
     var newHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>"+iframe.contents().find('html').html()+"</html>";
     iframe.contents().find('html').html(newHTML);
     //iframe.contents().prepend('<!DOCTYPE html>');
   });
});
```

Seems its a simple thing but I am doing a mistake.

Comment: I think, if you change the doctype on the fly, it won't change the way how the document is rendered. Maybe the doctype should already be set in the src of the iframe before changing its HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ms-dlgFrame').ready(function(){
     var iframe = $('.ms-dlgFrame');
     var newDoctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType(
        'html',
        '',
        ''
     );
     iframe[0].contentDocument.insertBefore(newDoctype,iframe[0].contentDocument.childNodes[0]);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you aren't able to target the contents of an iframe for security reasons.

Comment: This is only true if you don't control the target.